# Does the "Fade Away" UA ranger variant feature grant the effect of the Greater Invisibility spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, unearthed-arcana, invisibility

The new [UA: Class Feature Variants](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA_ClassFeatures.pdf) introduces a number of variant features that enhance or replace existing class features. One such feature, [Fade Away](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA_ClassFeatures.pdf#page=8), replaces the base ranger's 10th-level Hide in Plain Sight feature; its description states the following:

> You can use a bonus action to magically become invisible, along with any equipment you are wearing or carrying, until the start of your next turn.

**Does this feature effectively grant *Greater Invisiblity* until the Ranger's next turn, in the sense that *it is not interrupted by attacking*?**

This question is more of a sanity check, as, to me, this feature seems incredibly powerful. It would allow the Ranger to gain advantage on all of their attacks for an entire turn, while simultaneously imposing disadvantage on all attacks against them as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### It does not literally grant *greater invisibility* but it does not end when you make an attack

Things do only what they say they do, and the Fade Away option doesn't say that it ends when making an attack. However you've forgotten a significant part of the feature:

> You can use a bonus action to magically become invisible, along with any equipment you are wearing or carrying, until the start of your next turn.
>
> Once you use this feature, **you can’t use it again until you finish a short or long rest.**

Compare this to the *invisibility* spell:

> A creature you touch becomes invisible until the spell ends. Anything the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target's person. **The spell ends for a target that attacks or casts a spell** [...]

You only use Fade Away once per rest which makes it *far* from game-breaking. It also lasts only one turn, unlike *greater invisibility*. Also keep in mind that this is a 10th level feature so it isn't coming into play until much further along character advancement.